# SELECT Statement, with additional logic, in order to modify certain records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

How do I formulate a `SELECT` statement that can also modify a `Query` result.

I have the following table:

```
ID    Startdate     Enddate        Category

0,  "2021-05-05", "2021-05-20", "First Category" 
1,  "2021-05-06", "2021-05-10", "First Category"
2,  "2021-05-07", "2021-05-10", "First Category"
3,  "2021-05-08", "2021-05-15", "First Category"
4,  "2021-05-20", "2021-05-22", "Second Category"
5,  "2021-05-21", "2021-05-24", "Second Category"
6,  "2021-05-23", "2021-05-24", "First Category"
```

The SQL statement to get all these records is quite basic, however I need all the records that belong in a sequence of categories (0-3, 4-5, 6), the `Startdate` of all the records in the sequence, have to be set to the `Startdate` of the first record of the sequence.

So, the following result is expected:

```
ID    Startdate     Enddate        Category

0,  "2021-05-05", "2021-05-20", "First Category" 
1,  "2021-05-05", "2021-05-10", "First Category"  //changed Startdate
2,  "2021-05-05", "2021-05-10", "First Category"  //changed Startdate
3,  "2021-05-05", "2021-05-15", "First Category"  //changed Startdate
4,  "2021-05-20", "2021-05-22", "Second Category"
5,  "2021-05-20", "2021-05-24", "Second Category" //changed Startdate
6,  "2021-05-23", "2021-05-24", "First Category"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, but you don't want to reduce the number of rows, just to store the information.  I would suggest a running `max()` to determine where an "island" starts, a cumulative sum to calculate the "island" each row is in.  And finally a window function for what you want:

```
select t.*,
       min(startdate) over (partition by category, grp) as group_startdate
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_enddate >= startdate then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by category order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(enddate) over (partition by category order by startdate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_enddate
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50d374e8fe0716529945c42df314a056) is a db<>fiddle.